# For loop to convert series of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop that does the exact same thing as this code (quests is an array):

```
Quest0.text = quests[0]
Quest1.text = quests[1]
Quest2.text = quests[2]
Quest3.text = quests[3]
Quest4.text = quests[4]
Quest5.text = quests[5]
Quest6.text = quests[6]
Quest7.text = quests[7]
Quest8.text = quests[8]
Quest9.text = quests[9]
Quest10.text = quests[10]
Quest11.text = quests[11]
Quest12.text = quests[12]
Quest13.text = quests[13]
Quest14.text = quests[14]
Quest15.text = quests[15]
```

So far all I've got is this (activeQuests is the length of the array quests):

```
var q = 0;
for (q=0; q <= activeQuests; q++) {
    Quest0.text = quests[q]
}
```

But I don't know how to get it to do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `eval` but you probably shouldn't. You should probably rethink your approach if you have such obviously array-like data that you are manipulating manually element by element.

Check out this blog post from Marco van Hylckama Vlieg: ["Variable Variables in Javascript"](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2007/06/14/variable_variables_in_javascri). Relevant snippet:

> ...using the fact that all global variables are held in the window
>   array.
>
> ```
> var i=1;
> window['name' + i] = 'Marco';
> document.write('got ' + name1);
> ```
>
> There we go! Nice, clean and no eval() necessary."

Comment: might want to add a reference.. http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2007/06/14/variable_variables_in_javascri

Comment: @amosrivera: Thanks, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need to know more to give you exact code, but in order to address a variable by string, it needs to be a property of an object.  For example

```
window.example = 'hello world';
alert(window['example']);
```

So it really depends on what your `QuestN` variables are.  Are they id's of `<input>` elements?  Are they global variables?  Are they defined in local scope with the `var` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change how `Quest..` are defined then define them as an array so you can do:

```
Quest[q].text = quests[q];
```

if you can't then temporarily create an array of `Quest..` objects:

```
var QUESTS = [];
QUESTS[0] = Quest0;
QUESTS[1] = Quest1;
QUESTS[2] = Quest2;
QUESTS[3] = Quest3;
QUESTS[4] = Quest4;
QUESTS[5] = Quest5;
QUESTS[6] = Quest6;
QUESTS[7] = Quest7;
QUESTS[8] = Quest8;
QUESTS[9] = Quest9;
QUESTS[10] = Quest10;
QUESTS[11] = Quest11;
QUESTS[12] = Quest12;
QUESTS[13] = Quest13;
QUESTS[14] = Quest14;
QUESTS[15] = Quest15;
```

Then you can do:

```
for (var q=0; q<=activeQuests; q++) {
    QUESTS[q].text = quests[q]
}
```

Obviously this is an uglier solution but much better than `eval` IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off keeping the "quests" array than defining a different variable to each index.

However if you want to loop try `eval("Quest" + q + ".text = quests[q]")` in the loop.